# How to stop indexing in PhpStorm?

Tags: phpstorm

Today I open my project in PhpStorm.

Then PhpStorm start indexing on files just like that

[image]

and updates.

[image]

Anyone please tell me how to stop it.

Comment: Is it a locally stored project? Any symlinks in a project? What IDE version it is? Remove everything from "Include paths" at File | Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP. Mark `vendor`, temp, log and build tools output folders as excluded: right click > Mark as > excluded

Comment: yes it is local stored project

Comment: my issue is not resolve with your answer

Comment: Please contact PhpStorm support directly via Help > Contact Support attaching the logs (Help > Compress Logs & Show in ...). You didn't provide much information about the issue so we can only guess what's happening with the indexing here.

Answer (score 6):

You can stop synchronizing/indexing each time you switch to the IDEA and it's quite useful when dealing with big projects and outside build process which triggers indexing.

Just disable checkbox `System Settings -> Synchronize files on frame or editor tab activation`.

Make sure you run indexing manually to update hints when needed through `Synchronize` menu (Cmd-Alt-Y on Mac).

[image: System Settings]

Answer (score 0):

Indexing temporarily may be an option, but by disabling the indexing your project will not be fully indexed and you may be missing some functionality (actually what makes PhpStorm useful).

> it is a core feature, all WebStorm functionality (syntax/error highlighting, code completion, code inspections, navigation, refactoring, code coverage, search, etc.) is based on it.

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207671405/comments/208579689

You did not write why you want to disable. Is it using too much CPU (which sometimes happens)?

What you can do instead is:

- disable some directories for indexing - e.g. logs, automatically generated test files, build directories, unused sources. Either click on directory and in context menu select *Mark Directory as* | *Excluded* or in *Settings* choose *Directories* mark the directories as *Excluded* there. In my experience, **this usually fixed high CPU usage for PhpStorm in my projects**. **Restart PhpStorm after that**
- reduce the number of threads: *Help* | *Find Action* | *Registry* | *caches.indexerThreadsCount*, maybe also *caches.scanningThreadsCount* (see https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/360010215320/comments/360002619339)
- try invalidating caches and restart: File > Invalidate Caches (I never used that but it might help), see also https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207671405/comments/208579689
- if you are using several similar projects, maybe the plugin "[Shared Project Indexes](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/shared-indexes.html)" is useful (have not tried this out)